# OpenGL Java 3D Cube Rotation

Tags: java, opengl, youtube, 3d

I'm learning 3D  OpenGL.

I'm watching thebennybox's videos for learnig.
but now I am quite confused.

My cube seems to be three sides only compared with his tutorial video.

I have tried out for days but still can't figured out why ?

[benny's tutorial video Start watching at 19:37](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LJU70o8QXs&index=17&list=PLEETnX-uPtBXP_B2yupUKlflXBznWIlL5)

[mine program execution 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIRDtMMUp1k)

Mine Cube seems to have less sides.

I'm wondering that whether the sides are colored.

Rotation Code:

```
public Matrix4f initRotation(float x, float y, float z) 
{
    Matrix4f rx = new Matrix4f();
    Matrix4f ry = new Matrix4f();
    Matrix4f rz = new Matrix4f();

    x = (float)Math.toRadians(x);
    y = (float)Math.toRadians(y);
    z = (float)Math.toRadians(z);

    rz.m[0][0] = (float)Math.cos(z);rz.m[0][1] = -(float)Math.sin(z);rz.m[0][2] = 0;                rz.m[0][3] = 0;
    rz.m[1][0] = (float)Math.sin(z);rz.m[1][1] = (float)Math.cos(z);rz.m[1][2] = 0;                 rz.m[1][3] = 0;
    rz.m[2][0] = 0;                 rz.m[2][1] = 0;                 rz.m[2][2] = 1;                 rz.m[2][3] = 0;
    rz.m[3][0] = 0;                 rz.m[3][1] = 0;                 rz.m[3][2] = 0;                 rz.m[3][3] = 1;

    rx.m[0][0] = 1;                 rx.m[0][1] = 0;                 rx.m[0][2] = 0;                 rx.m[0][3] = 0;
    rx.m[1][0] = 0;                 rx.m[1][1] = (float)Math.cos(x);rx.m[1][2] = -(float)Math.sin(x);rx.m[1][3] = 0;
    rx.m[2][0] = 0;                 rx.m[2][1] = (float)Math.sin(x);rx.m[2][2] = (float)Math.cos(x);rx.m[2][3] = 0;
    rx.m[3][0] = 0;                 rx.m[3][1] = 0;                 rx.m[3][2] = 0;                 rx.m[3][3] = 1;

    ry.m[0][0] = (float)Math.cos(y);ry.m[0][1] = 0;                 ry.m[0][2] = -(float)Math.sin(y);ry.m[0][3] = 0;
    ry.m[1][0] = 0;                 ry.m[1][1] = 1;                 ry.m[1][2] = 0;                 ry.m[1][3] = 0;
    ry.m[2][0] = (float)Math.sin(y);ry.m[2][1] = 0;                 ry.m[2][2] = (float)Math.cos(y);ry.m[2][3] = 0;
    ry.m[3][0] = 0;                 ry.m[3][1] = 0;                 ry.m[3][2] = 0;                 ry.m[3][3] = 1;

    m = rz.mul(ry.mul(rx)).getM();

    return this;
}
```

And import box.obj:

```
 o cube
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -0.999999
v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
usemtl Material
s off
f 1 2 3 
f 1 3 4
f 5 8 7
f 5 7 6
f 1 5 6
f 1 6 2
f 2 6 7
f 2 7 3
f 3 7 8
f 3 8 4
f 5 1 4
f 5 4 8
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have your view / projection matrix set up, that you're only rotating the cube but you're not positioning the cube or the camera correctly.

Comment: I think that my thought is right.......  I really don't have some sides of the cube after adding the projection. But I still can't figured out why. My new video [Cube less sides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIqgTVD-zuk)

Answer (score 0):

In the video, you can see that some faces are reversed (you can only see them from the inside of the cube). This means that somewhere in your code, the order of face indices is clockwise instead of counter-clockwise (or the other way around). By default, OpenGL only shows one side of a face, a technique called "face culling".

Try using a different cube .obj model, such as the one below. If that doesn't help, you have to go through all the code that handles the .obj file and eventually displays it with OpenGL.

```
 o cube
v  0.0  0.0  0.0
v  0.0  0.0  -1.0
v  0.0  -1.0  0.0
v  0.0  -1.0  -1.0
v  -1.0  0.0  0.0
v  -1.0  0.0  -1.0
v  -1.0  -1.0  0.0
v  -1.0  -1.0  -1.0
usemtl Material
s off
f  1  7  5
f  1  3  7 
f  1  4  3 
f  1  2  4 
f  3  8  7 
f  3  4  8 
f  5  7  8 
f  5  8  6 
f  1  5  6 
f  1  6  2 
f  2  6  8 
f  2  8  4
```

Comment: Sorry.. I have been busy these days. I have searched for the Learn OpenGL  so I know you mean about the clockwise and counter-clockwise.                                       But I don't get it with flipping the reverse faces in blender.

Comment: You mean I should try this model and ignore vector normal and 1//2 becomes 2   7//2 becomes 14 ?

Comment: I have try your obj. But I think it's not that way. I uploaded the new video with winding adjustment you can watch this  [new video](https://youtu.be/E4yd6rgL9fQ)